# The Infamous Entity Framework - Aggregate Root Issue

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I have stumbled through StackOverflow and Google and other sites but could not grasp the concept of how to implement it.

Here I have a very very simple model: An `Item` and an `ItemActivity`. It is clear that the `Item` is the aggregate root and the `ItemActivity` is an entity.

So according to DDD principles I should only implement `ItemRepository`. Besides its own -lets say- CRUD operations the `ItemRepository` should also manage its child entity's, `ItemActivity`'s, CRUD operations too.

And here comes some implementation issues:

1. Should I implement child entity operations in the domain or
   repository.
2. Loading all child entities related to an item or navigating to them
   is OK with Entity Framework. Loading the root with `.include(..)` will
   do the work. But what about updading an `ItemActivity` or even
   deleting an `ItemActivity`? Removing them from the collection does not
   persist.
3. Assume that I have to find all activities within a time span. How
   can such a query be implemented while I cannot query over
   `ItemActivity` or worse there does not exist any
   `ItemActivityRepository` at all.
4. Is there a sample covering this topic. There are a lot of articles
   written about it, many answers without concrete code and theoretical
   coverages but please, are there any **real** samples. I have worked on
   Microsoft Spain N-Layered DDD Sample but it is not detailed enough.

Best regards.

Comment: Don't make the mistake to consider the Aggregate Root a container for children objects. And forget about anything related to persistence, when defining any Domain object. And that includes forgetting about relational db principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.Should I implement child entity operations in the domain or repository.

No. the repository manipulates the aggregate only.

> 2.Loading all child entities related to an item or navigating to them is OK with Entity Framework. Loading the root with .include(..) will
>   do the work. But what about updading an ItemActivity or even deleting
>   an ItemActivity? Removing them from the collection does not persist.

```
  Item.getActivity().updateRemark("...");
  ItemRepository.store(Item);
```

> 3.Assume that I have to find all activities within a time span.

You'd better make ItemActivity another aggregate root if you need to query them by range. Smaller aggregates helps this case.

```
4.Is there a sample covering this topic.
```

The famous [Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/). There is some sample code(especially in Part 1) relates to your case closely.

Comment: The update is simple but how do delete? Removing the item from the collection just deletes the relationship but leaves the orphaned item

Comment: @LiviuM. I'm not familiar with Entity Framework, but I think the deletion depends on how you define the mapping. In JPA/Hibernate, the child will be deleted when removed from the collection if it is mapped as component.

Comment: In EF up to 6.1. this is not the case.